# RStudio locally + R cloudly

Tags: r, ssh, rstudio, rstudio-server

Is there any way to run RStudio locally on my machine but using a remote machine running R as engine instead of my local R install?

To be clear I know that there's the possibility to use RStudio server with a web GUI but I am asking something different. I want to use both my local RStudio app connected to a remote machine running R (possibly through ssh).

Is it possible?

Comment: You can check out http://www.dominoup.com/, which allows you to run R code on the cloud from a local instance of RStudio.

Comment: This is not currently possible with Rstudio.

Answer (score 1):

The [High Performance Computing Task View](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html) may be of some assistance. Unfortunately, I haven't found an easy way to do this and instead simply forward a local RStudio instance on our Linux cluster over X using SSH. You'll need [XQuartz](https://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/) if you're on OS X.

I suppose that RStudio Server is probably a better way of doing this. You can easily tie in the RStudio authentication to PAM on your Linux server to authenticate.

```
ssh -X user@server.com rstudio
```